# When a new tab is created in firefox in selenium on Mac OS its not identified

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am new to selenium and MAC. i've searched and found no one who had this issue and hence posting the issue. I generated a new tab in my test and I am verifying if the new tab generated  is pointing to my link using the following code.

```
List<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    if(tabs.size() > 1) {
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

How ever the newly created tab is not being identified and hence the test is failing, to be exact I am getting tabs.size()  = 1 when I am expecting the value to be 2.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance. the language I am using is Java. This feature is working as expected on other browsers.

Comment: How are you creating the new tab?

Comment: what is your requirement? setting focus on a specific tab or counting the tabs?

Comment: @AndyPerfect : creating new tab : 
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).build().perform();


        controls.Links.get(0).click();


        Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
        action2.keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).build().perform();

 My requirement is to browse to a link and then check if the navigated link is as expected.  Thanks a lot..